# Correct value of kairosdb.datastore.cassandra.host_list

Tags: cassandra, kairosdb

I have a 4 node Cassandra Cluster and have KairosDB running on all of those 4 nodes. The default value of `kairosdb.datastore.cassandra.host_list` is `localhost`. Should I be specifying all the Cassandra nodes here? If so, how can I be sure the load is balancing between all 4 nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From their code it seems they use Hector to talk to Cassandra. In that case the connection pooling of Cassandra and loadbalancing is done automatically by hector implementation and you don't have to worry about it. So, give it the listen address of all Cassandra nodes that you have for each kairosdb instance and you should be good to go.

Code:
https://github.com/proofpoint/kairosdb/blob/master/src/main/java/org/kairosdb/datastore/cassandra/HectorConfiguration.java

Comment: Also had to set kairosdb.datastore.cassandra.hector.loadBalancingPolicy in kairodb.properties. Else it was picking up the first node in the list.